# Type mismatch when call java generic Java method from Scala code

Tags: java, scala, generics, scala-java-interop

I have a n-quantity of Java classes with one superclass - data model.
The list of the classes is input parameter to Scala method in which I want to create
resultStreams and have to create call Java generic methods from process method.
Could you write how to resolve it?
I tried to use [_ <: SpecificRecordBase], [SpecificRecordBase] in the method calling, but had the same result.

Error

```
Error:(146, 88) type mismatch;
 found   : Class[_$3] where type _$3 <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase
 required: Class[org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase]
Note: _$3 <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase, but Java-defined class Class is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase`. (SLS 3.2.10)
                AvroHelper.deSerializeAvroObject(record.value, cl))(TypeInformation.of(cl)))
```

Scala code

```
object GenerickRunnerStackOverFlow  {
  def process(inputClasses :  List[Class[_ <: SpecificRecordBase]],): Unit = {
    val newStream: DataStream[KafkaSourceType] = env.addSource(....)).uid(...).filter(...)

    val resultStreams = inputClasses .map(
      cl => newStream.map(record =>
                AvroHelper.deSerializeAvroObject(record.value, cl))(TypeInformation.of(cl)))

        ...
  }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val topicToClasses: List[Class[_ <: SpecificRecordBase]] = List(Types.RECORD_1.getClassType, Types.RECORD_1.getClassType.getClassType)
        process(topicToClasses)

    }
}
```

Java method spec

```
public static <A extends SpecificRecord> A deSerializeAvroObject(byte[] object, Class<A> clazz){ ...}
```

Model

```
    public class Record1 extends SpecificRecordBase {}
    public class Record2 extends SpecificRecordBase {}
    ...
    public enum Types {
      RECORD_1(Record1.class),
      RECORD_2(Record2.class);
      ....

      private Class<? extends SpecificRecordBase> clazz;
      public Class<? extends SpecificRecordBase> getClassType() {return this.clazz;}
}
```

Also I have the same message error with Scala addSink method:

```
def addSink(sinkFunction : org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction[T]) : org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink[T] = { /* compiled code */ }
```

I write the wrapper method:

```
def addSinkWithSpecificRecordBase[A <: SpecificRecordBase](
    stream: DataStream[A],
    sink: BucketingSink[A]): DataStreamSink[A] = stream.addSink(sink)
```

In result of execution:

```
val result = topicToSinkStream.foreach { el =>
  val stream: DataStream[_ <: SpecificRecordBase] = el._2._1
  val sink: BucketingSink[_ <: SpecificRecordBase] = el._2._2
  addSinkWithSpecificRecordBase(stream, sink)
}
```

There was an error:

```
Error:(209, 37) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[_$9] where type _$9 <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase
 required: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase]
Note: _$9 <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase, but class DataStream is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
      addSinkWithSpecificRecordBase(stream, sink)
```

Where topicToSinkStream is:

```
Map[String, (DataStream[_ <: SpecificRecordBase], BucketingSink[_ <: SpecificRecordBase])]
```

I also tried to eliminate the SpecificRecordBase in method gemeric description and Add + and - to method parameters description. But there is no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the type of `AvroHelper.deSerializeAvroObject(record.value, cl)` is `SpecificRecordBase` (`_ <: SpecificRecordBase` is only allowed in type *parameters*, not here). The fix is to extract a helper function:

```
def processClass[A <: SpecificRecordBase](cl: Class[A], newStream: DataStream[KafkaSourceType]) = 
  newStream.map(record => AvroHelper.deSerializeAvroObject(record.value, cl))(TypeInformation.of(cl)))
```

(if you define it locally you can also use `newStream` without making it an argument) and then

```
val resultStreams = inputClasses.map(cl => processClass(cl, newStream))
```

Comment: Thank you) Could you please help me with method addSink of DataStream[A]. I updated the questions.

Comment: The type of your `topicToSinkStream` allows having a `DataStream` of one record type and `BucketingSink` of another, so it needs to be fixed first.